# How to find parametric equation between two points in line integral?

Tags: integration, parametric, line-integrals

[In this example how can we find parametric equations of x and y.]

[1] [question]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTOnW.png

[1] [Solution]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ao7.jpg

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: This example is solved in my book but I did not understand how we find parametric equations.

Comment: Post the solution so that someone can explain it to you. Without it someone may go a different way and may complicate you more :)

Comment: I uploaded solution.

Comment: Answered analytically down below. Make sure that you ask me if you need to understand something and let me know. Also, make sure you approve the answer if it's the one that fits you so that the thread will become answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you have that your segment goes from $(0,0)$ to $(1,2)$. If you let $t$ be a parameter that expresses the value of $1$, then $2$ will be $2t$.

So your $x=t$ and your $y=2t$ but they are bounded from $0$ to $1$ since your ending point is $(1,2)$. So, $ t \in [0,1]$.

Then you get $dy = d(2t) = 2$ and your integral becomes :

$\int_C 3xydy = \int_0^1 3(t)(2t)(2)dt = \int_0^1 12t^2dt = [4t^3]_0^1 = 4 $

The second solution is when you go backwards, from $(1,2)$ to $(0,0)$. 
So your starting point is $(1,2)$ which means $1$ for $x$ and $2$ for $y$.

Since you go backwards to $(0,0)$, it's your staring point minus something that is still in the boundaries. So you get :

$x= 1-t$ and $y=2-2t$ with $ t \in [0,1]$. Thus $dy = d(2-2t) = -2dt$

Then solve the integral : $\int_0^1 3(1-t)(2-2t)(-2)dt$.